# Torque for engine mount stud

Tags: saturn, fastener, motor-mounts

I replaced the upper engine mount for my 2000 Saturn SL2. The mount is attached via three nuts to  studs in the engine block. While removing the old mount, one of the studs unscrewed instead of the nut (as I had hoped). Well, I got the nut off and installed the new mount. The nuts have a torque spec of 52 lb-ft, but I could not find any info about the stud. I spun it on "tightly" (using a small wrench on the 7 mm hex on the top of the stud). Is there any spcefic, or general, guide lines for torquing studs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you torque the nut up, you are torquing the whole stud.

I don’t think you should be torquing the stud on its own.  To torque it down, you will either have to be driving it down to the bottom of the threaded hole, or the unthreaded part of the stud (if there is some) will be being forced into the threads of the block.  I guess that is why you couldn’t find any torque specs for the stud.

Just screw it in and torque the nut.